# 'MaxDegreeOfParallelism' for Array.Parallel?

Tags: f#, arrays, parallel-processing

Is it possible to set 'MaxDegreeOfParallelism' (that is maximum number of threads to use) for Array.Parallel module since under the hood [it uses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee821128.aspx) Parallel.For?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/parallelextensions/thread/72e9db29-77a3-4db3-9193-86425264cd4e), it seems that there is no way to limit the number of threads globally in the final version of Parallel Extensions. An alternative to what brian suggests would be to use PLINQ (which works with parallel sequences) instead of functions that work with arrays.

This can be done using the `PSeq` module from [F# PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/). It provides functions such as `PSeq.map`, `PSeq.filter` and many other that work with *parallel sequences* (which can be also nicely composed using pipelining). For *parallel sequences*, you can use the [WithDegreeOfParallelism extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383719.aspx) to specify the behavior.

<strike>You could implement a wrapper function for it:</strike>
[EDIT: It is already there!]

```
let withDegreeOfParallelism n (pq:ParallelQuery<_>) = 
  pq.WithDegreeOfParallelsm(n)
```

And then write:

```
let res = 
  data |> PSeq.map (fun n -> ...)
       |> PSeq.withDegreeOfParallelism ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism
       |> Array.ofSeq
```

This may have different perfromance, because it is implemented differently than functions in the `Array.Parallel` module, but this certainly depends on your scenario.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. That wrapper is already a part of `PSeq` module (as `PSeq.withDegreeOfParallelism`), for what I know. For me, the only problem with `ParallelQuery<T>` is it's deferred execution.

Comment: You're right, it's already there - I corrected my post. The fact that it is deferred means that if you sequence multiple operations using `|>`, the framework can run them at once (with some smart optimizations), while `Array.Parallel` runs each operation separately (so it may create a larger number of tasks - which may, or may not be an issue...).

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think so.

You can always create your own versions of any of the methods in the [Array.Parallel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee821135.aspx) module, using the source code from `array.fs` (in the [CTP release](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=444005fb-e627-4feb-b51d-13d6a3b4b8ed&displaylang=en)) as a starter.

Comment: That's what I thought so. Nevertheless, thanks for assuring me. Sources form CTP release are certainly going to be valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I want say at most 10 threads I've been replacing:

```
myArray 
|> Array.Parallel.iter (fun item -> doWork item)
```

with

```
let maxPara = 10
myArray
|> Array.splitInto maxPara
|> Array.Parallel.iter (fun items -> items |> List.iter (fun item -> doWork item))
```